# New installation not letting me boot to windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, 13.10

I have an HP Pavilion running Windows 7. Not wanting to make any changes to my 1TB hard drive, I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a separate 40GB hard drive in the same computer. After installation, I can neither boot to the Windows drive or select the Windows drive from the GRUB menu. GRUB menu only shows options for Ubuntu. I have tried booting to the Windows drive from the bios, but it simply passes it right up like its not there and boots to the Ubuntu drive. The only way to boot to Windows is to disconnect the Ubuntu drive itself, but I don't want to open the tower every time I want to switch between them. Looking for some help. Can I get the Ubuntu drive to recognize the Windows drive maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run `sudo update-grub` which should search all connected hard drives and find the Windows loader, thus adding it to grub. Normally this would have been discovered during the installation of Ubuntu by default, however.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. Out put looked like this:Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
done
I know the drive is working because I can see it in the Disk Management and I can access the files from Ubuntu.

Comment: Try out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and on other options select 'Repair Windows Boot Files'